# How to read songs playlist from website or static IP for my Android media player project

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media

I am currently making an Android media player app in Java, Its job is simple to make user enjoy my friends raps using online streaming. His songs are on reverbnation.com. I would upload a playlist having all the links of his songs online (any basic website). When the user starts the app (refreshes), it should read the playlist file and start playing the latest songs which are mentioned in that playlist. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should look for a dedicated API. If the page allows such things, there should be some kind of web API for logging in and asking for playlists.

If there is no such thing, you can try to download the specific page and parse its code. You should look for song entry pattern, so you can get the link and/or song name.

Comment: Do you know any such api?
can you tell me something more about this, for instance how should i do it, etc?
thank you very much

Comment: Unfortunately, seems like they don't have any public API for developers. See:
http://support.reverbnation.com/reverbnation/topics/reverbnation_web_service_api_for_developers


Most of well known services have a set of web functions for getting and setting data related to the service. See:
https://dev.twitter.com/